# How to parse a specific Netbackup bpimagelist format data file, records separated by empty line, each line with data label and label

Tags: arrays, string, bash

NBU bpimagelist data output format snippet here.
**A single record is separated by blank or empty line**, however each line contains a variable length data label separated by a colon, some random number of spaces, then a variable data content. A single record can be of variable length and not a specific number of lines.

I'd like to convert this file into a comma separated format for import into Excel in order to analyze it. I was able to extract the data labels without problem.

```
Client:            <hostname>
Backup ID:         <hostname>_1396674012
Policy:            M-PORTWAREW2K03-PROD-CLF
Policy Type:       MS-Windows (13)
Proxy Client:      (none specified)
Creator:           root
Name1:             (none specified)
Sched Label:       MONTHLY_FULL
Schedule Type:     FULL (0)
Retention Level:   5 weeks (4)
Backup Time:       Sat Apr  5 01:00:12 2014 (1396674012)
Elapsed Time:      2448 second(s)
Expiration Time:   Sat Apr  3 01:00:12 2021 (1617426012)
Compressed:        no
Client Encrypted:  no
Kilobytes:         37997291
Number of Files:   240819
Number of Copies:  1
Number of Fragments:   1
Histogram:         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
DB Compressed:     no
Files File Name:   M-PORTWAREW2K03-PROD-CLF_1396674012_FULL.f
...many more lines of files with data labels and data per record.
```

I'd like to get data into a csv format like this...

```
Client,Backup ID,Policy,Policy Type,Proxy Client,Creator,...more labels
<hostname>,<hostname>_ID#,M-PORTWAREW2K03-PROD-CLF,MS-Windows (13),(none specified),root,(none specified),MONTHLY_FULL,FULL (0),5 weeks (4),Sat Apr  5 01:00:12 2014 (1396674012),...more...

# Write the output headers from the first file record - a single record is from blank line to blank line
# Get first record and pull out just the first column of data and output as single comma delimited line
HEADER=`sed '/^\s*$/q' $INPUTFILE | cut -d: -f1 | tr '\n' ','`
echo -e $HEADER > $OUTFILE

# Repeat the above on all lines in the file but pull the data (2nd column after : instead and output as comma delimited
# where "cut -d: -f2-" removes the first column of data to left of colon delimiter, and
# where "tr -d ' ' " removes the leading white space between colon and start of data, and
# where "tr '\n' ',' " or "paster -d, -s" replaces newlines with commas between data.
```

NOW, how to add a trailing newline between records?

```
sed '/^\s*$/d' $INPUTFILE | cut -d: -f2- | tr -d ' ' | tr '\n' ',' >> $OUTFILE
```

So essentially reformat all data lines, showing only the data to the right of the colon delimiter (removing the intervening spaces between the delimiter and the start of the data), removing the line feeds between each line (as they are in the source) and replacing with commas, until all data for a record is output. When the next blank line is reached in the source, output is advanced to a new line and the process should repeat until end of data.

```
Client:            <hostname>
Backup ID:         <hostname>_1349499621
Policy:            M-PORTWAREW2K03-PROD-CLF
Policy Type:       MS-Windows (13)
Proxy Client:      (none specified)
Creator:           root
Name1:             (none specified)
Sched Label:       MONTHLY_FULL
Schedule Type:     FULL (0)
Retention Level:   7 years (14)
Backup Time:       Sat Oct  6 01:00:21 2012 (1349499621)
Elapsed Time:      3457 second(s)
Expiration Time:   Sat Oct  5 01:00:21 2019 (1570251621)
Compressed:        no
Client Encrypted:  no
Kilobytes:         37090868
Number of Files:   215304
Number of Copies:  1
Number of Fragments:   6
Histogram:         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
DB Compressed:     no
Files File Name:   M-PORTWAREW2K03-PROD-CLF_1349499621_FULL.f
Previous Backup Files File Name:   (none specified)
Parent Backup Image File Name:   (none specified)
SW Version:        (none specified)
Options:           0x0
MPX:               1
TIR Info:          0
TIR Expiration:    Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969 (0)
Keyword:           (none specified)
Ext Security Info: no
File Restore Raw:  no
Image Dump Level:  0
File System Only:  no
Object Descriptor: (none specified)
Previous BI Time:  Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969 (0)
BI Full Time:      Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969 (0)
Request Pid:       0
Backup Status:     0
Stream Number:     0
Backup Copy:       Standard (0)
Files File size:     0
PFI type:     0
IMAGE_ATTRIBUTE:     0
Primary Copy:      1
Image Type:        0  (Regular)
Job ID:            2123444
Num Resumes:       0
Resume Expiration: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969 (0)
Data Classification:    (none specified)
Data_Classification_ID: (none specified)
Storage Lifecycle Policy:    (none specified)
Storage Lifecycle Policy Version:    0
STL_Completed:      0
Remote Expiration Time: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969 (0)
Origin Master Server:  (none specified)
Origin Master GUID:    (none specified)
Snap Time:      Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969 (0)
IR Enabled:      no
Client Character Set:     0
Image On Hold:     0
Indexing Status:   0
Copy number:       1
 Fragment:         1
 Kilobytes:        0
 Remainder:        0
 Media Type:       Media Manager (2)
 Density:          hcart3 (20)
 File Num:         8
 ID:               K14753
 Host:             <some_other_host>
 Block Size:       262144
 Offset:           1220388
 Media Date:       Fri Oct  5 19:00:10 2012 (1349478010)
 Dev Written On:   2
 Flags:            0x40  (Tape Encrypted)
 Media Descriptor:        ?
 Expiration Time:  Sat Oct  5 01:00:21 2019 (1570251621)
 MPX:              1
 retention_lvl:    7 years (14)
 Try to Keep Time:  Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969 (0)
 Copy Creation Time:  Sat Oct  6 01:57:58 2012 (1349503078)
 Data Format:      Undefined
 checkpoint:       0
 resume num:       0
 Key tag:                  41f841dd750ef07e68cc5387629bb22d21933ca3a4ea204a01abbee2ba98cd44
 STL tag:          *NULL*
 Copy on hold:     0
Copy number:       1
 Fragment:         2
 Kilobytes:        6423296
 Remainder:        0
 Media Type:       Media Manager (2)
 Density:          hcart3 (20)
 File Num:         9
 ID:               K14753
 Host:             amarlp67
 Block Size:       262144
 Offset:           1235772
 Media Date:       Fri Oct  5 19:00:10 2012 (1349478010)
 Dev Written On:   2
 Flags:            0x40  (Tape Encrypted)
 Media Descriptor:        ?
 checkpoint:       0
 resume num:       0
 Copy on hold:     0
Copy number:       1
 Fragment:         3
 Kilobytes:        3038464
 Remainder:        0
 Media Type:       Media Manager (2)
 Density:          hcart3 (20)
 File Num:         10
 ID:               K14753
 Host:             amarlp67
 Block Size:       262144
 Offset:           1538917
 Media Date:       Fri Oct  5 19:00:10 2012 (1349478010)
 Dev Written On:   2
 Flags:            0x40  (Tape Encrypted)
 Media Descriptor:        ?
 checkpoint:       0
```

etcetera, until a blank line. Every record could have a random number of fragments.

I'm open to any methodology to solve this, though the simplest and most elegant code will probably be the most efficient. Realize that the source data is millions of rows long.

Comment: stackoverflow isn't a free coding service (contrary to what many people seem to think). Stackoverflow **is** about helping people fix their code. You're expected to show that have tried to solve your own problem, either with code, or at least research. Please update your question to include you best attempt to solve your problem. Use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box to format code and data correctly (after you highlight it with your mouse). Good luck.

Comment: Indeed, I'm not looking for someone to do all the coding, just assistance in getting through this and since I'm newly posting to the site, I'm not aware of the formatting controls yet. Anyway, I have a snippet of code that successfully pulls a set of headers from the first data record.

Comment: ok, great. Just add the code to you question, and maybe the current output. if you are getting error messages, be sure to include them verbatim. The `{}` tool is very easy once you've used it. OR you can just precede all lines of code or data with 4 spaces (its the same thing as `{}`). Finally, indicate **in your question** if you are open to other tools to solve your problem. I would think `bash` and `awk` (mostly `awk`), will be able to solve this for you easily. Good luck.

Comment: Indeed, I'm new posting to the site, I'm not aware of the formatting controls yet. Anyway, here's snippet of my code...

HEADER=`sed '/^\s*$/q' $INPUTFILE | cut -d: -f1 | tr '\n' ','`
echo -e $HEADER > $OUTFILE

# Repeat the above on all lines in the file but pull the data (2nd column after : instead and output as comma delimited
#
# NOW, how to add a trailing newline between records
#
sed '/^\s*$/d' $INPUTFILE | cut -d: -f2- | tr -d ' ' | tr '\n' ',' >> $OUTFILE

Comment: Just click on the `edit` link at the bottom of your question and then look at the top left corner of the edit box. Note the **B** *I* (paper clip) ... `{}` ... tools. Each icon has a tool tip, so just hover over to see what formatting options are available to you. So for practice, move your code above into your question. Good luck.

Comment: Does every record have the exact same fields in the exact same order? If not, this will be too complicated for sed and cut.

Comment: Yes and no. Each record has the exact same order up to the point where there are more fragments to a file than just one. The fragment data is appended on additional lines after the file data and indented by one space character. At that point, all fragments and info are listed on following lines before the next record, which comes on a blank line.

Copy number:       3
 Fragment:         1
 Kilobytes:        38000760
 Remainder:        0

There are about a dozen lines per fragment.

Answer (score 0):

This code will generate CSV output from bpimagelist command:

```
echo "client_name, date1, date2, version, backupid, policy_name, client_type, proxy_client, creator, sched_label, sched_type, retention, backup_time, elapsed, expiration, compression, encryption, kbytes, num_files, copies, num_fragments, files_compressed, files_file, version, name1, options, primary, image_type, tir_info, tir_expiration, keywords, mpx, ext_security, raw, dump_lvl, fs_only, prev_BItime, BIfull_time, obj_desc, requestID, backup_stat, backup_copy, prev_image, jobid, num_resumes, resume_expr, ff_size, pfi_type, image_attrib, ss_classification_id, ss_name, ss_completed, snap_time, slp_version[, remoteExpiration, origin_master_server, origin_master_guid, ir_enabled, client_charset, hold, indexing_status"
bpimagelist -l | grep '^IMAGE' | sed -e 's/^IMAGE //' | tr ' ' ','
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on arainchi's answer, sometimes the problem is not to parse the output you're given, but rather to see what other output you might get.

In the case of netbackup, there are typically command line flags to give you different output formats.

If you use the `-l` flag like arainchi did, you'll get a much more easily parseable report.  Read the Fine Man Page.  :)

If I really did have to parse something like this, I'd use perl, and set `$/` to be a pair of newlines (`\n\n`).  That will let perl treat each record as a single "line".  Then you can process the "line" as needed.